# Building for iOS fails with Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on iOS 12.4

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I suddenly stumbled upon the error `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` on iOS 12.4.

This is what I get to see once the app starts running and the splash shows.

[image]

This happens on iOS 12.4 but it doesn't happen on iOS 13.2. I checked out to earlier commits of my repository where the problem didn't exist but it didn't help.

Backtrace:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf600
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Regular;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Bold;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red255\green255\blue255;\red31\green31\blue36;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;\csgenericrgb\c100000\c100000\c100000;\csgenericrgb\c12054\c12284\c14131;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab593
\pard\tx593\pardeftab593\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf2 \cb3 thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #0: 0x00000001190313ae dyld`__abort_with_payload + 10
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #1: 0x0000000119030ba0 dyld`abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 82
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #2: 0x0000000119030bd2 dyld`abort_with_payload + 9
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #3: 0x000000010eb8d8c1 dyld_sim`abort_with_payload + 34
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #4: 0x000000010eb84fe0 dyld_sim`dyld::halt(char const*) + 343
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #5: 0x000000010eb8510a dyld_sim`dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 167
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #6: 0x00000001185a4122 libdyld.dylib`dyld_stub_binder + 282
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #7: 0x000000010eb2e000 Relation Portal
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #8: 0x000000010eb0ae0e Relation Portal`-[CDVViewController __init](self=0x00007f8cfbe07b30, _cmd="__init") at CDVViewController.m:82:9
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #9: 0x000000010eb0aefe Relation Portal`-[CDVViewController initWithNibName:bundle:](self=0x00007f8cfbe07b30, _cmd="initWithNibName:bundle:", nibNameOrNil=0x0000000000000000, nibBundleOrNil=0x0000000000000000) at CDVViewController.m:91:5
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #10: 0x000000010ead2bb4 Relation Portal`-[MainViewController initWithNibName:bundle:](self=0x0000000000000000, _cmd="initWithNibName:bundle:", nibNameOrNil=0x0000000000000000, nibBundleOrNil=0x0000000000000000) at MainViewController.m:34:12
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #11: 0x000000010eb0b05b Relation Portal`-[CDVViewController init](self=0x0000000000000000, _cmd="init") at CDVViewController.m:104:12
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #12: 0x000000010ead2c6b Relation Portal`-[MainViewController init](self=0x0000000000000000, _cmd="init") at MainViewController.m:46:12
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #13: 0x000000010ead2aa5 Relation Portal`-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](self=0x0000600003200d20, _cmd="application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:", application=0x00007f8cfe000e50, launchOptions=0x0000000000000000) at AppDelegate.m:35:27
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #14: 0x000000011edab731 UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 280
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #15: 0x000000011edad0cd UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3932
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #16: 0x000000011edb24e6 UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1617
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #17: 0x000000011e5f6a4e UIKitCore`__111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 904
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #18: 0x000000011e5ff346 UIKitCore`+[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #19: 0x000000011e5f6664 UIKitCore`-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #20: 0x000000011e5f6fc0 UIKitCore`-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1091
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #21: 0x000000011e5f5332 UIKitCore`__82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 782
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #22: 0x000000011e5f4fe9 UIKitCore`-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #23: 0x000000011e5f9d2e UIKitCore`__125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 576
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #24: 0x000000011e5fa988 UIKitCore`_performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #25: 0x000000011e5f9a95 UIKitCore`-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #26: 0x000000011e5fea48 UIKitCore`-[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #27: 0x000000011edb0dc8 UIKitCore`-[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 514
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #28: 0x000000011e96802f UIKitCore`-[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #29: 0x000000011dbdfd25 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #30: 0x000000011dbe9ad6 FrontBoardServices`__56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 283
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #31: 0x000000011dbe9300 FrontBoardServices`__40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #32: 0x000000011852ddb5 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #33: 0x00000001185312ba libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #34: 0x000000011dc1b0da FrontBoardServices`__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #35: 0x000000011dc1ad92 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 451
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #36: 0x000000011dc1b327 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 42
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #37: 0x0000000110cf0db1 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #38: 0x0000000110cf0633 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #39: 0x0000000110ceacef CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1231
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #40: 0x0000000110cea4d2 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #41: 0x00000001133ba2fe GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 65
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #42: 0x000000011edb3fc2 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 140
\f1\b \

\f0\b0   * frame #43: 0x000000010ead2a21 Relation Portal`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffee112d238) at main.m:32:22
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #44: 0x00000001185a2541 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
\f1\b \

\f0\b0     frame #45: 0x00000001185a2541 libdyld.dylib`start + 1}
```

Comment: This must be a main thread issue, after upgrading to new XCode even i got this issue for iOS 12, but didn't check on before i resolved the issue wether it was working or not!

Comment: I remember testing before for iOS 12.4 on the same XCode version (11.2) it didn't appear back then. Since I also reverted my code to there I suspect it's a setting issue.

Comment: Yes, in new XCode they have made main thread checking more strict!

Comment: @Niki Maybe my answer will help you too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in `printMultiTaskingInfo` was for me caused by my `config.xml`. The value below causes errors on older iOS versions:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

And don't forget to do

```
ionic build
```

After that. That was the main reason for me as to why I was still having the error.

Comment: Can you help me understand the solution and what exactly the problem was ?

Comment: The problem for me was that I was setting the orientation in `config.xml`. Doing this in ionic code instead solved my problem. So you need to remove the preference `orientation` and then run the command `ionic build`

Comment: Ohh okay, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try putting your printing function within main thread explicitly!

[image]

[image]

It had to be something related to main thread.

And for testing purpose without doing any changes what you can do is, uncheck main thread checker and try running it to get a clear picture,

[image]